# Why do my paragraphs overlap each other when using CSS Grid layout?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm new to CSS Grid.

My problem is that when I set `display: grid;` on the parent element that contains two mere paragraphs `<p>`, the paragraphs overlap one over the other rather than stacking normally one on top of each other, hence, making the container expand its height.

Two questions:

1. Why is this happening?
2. How can I fix this to make the paragraphs behave normally (stacking)?

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "avatar name   icon" "avatar date   date" "review review review";
  border: red 1px solid;
}

h3 {
  grid-area: name;
  margin: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
  grid-area: icon;
}

.date {
  grid-area: date;
}

p {
  grid-area: review;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
    <h3>Gene Kang</h3>
    <span class="date">December 29, 2016</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi harum, voluptatum perferendis dicta error blanditiis ipsum in nemo expedita delectus. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae in eius necessitatibus, impedit sapiente cupiditate laudantium perspiciatis neque dolore sequi laborum quo iure facere nobis minima, numquam illo sunt unde?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, maiores consectetur laboriosam distinctio libero pariatur at quasi aliquam ipsam provident eligendi eos quibusdam animi sapiente iste beatae ducimus cum temporibus unde, nobis totam odio sed ab! Voluptate soluta explicabo harum? Non, rerum nulla repellat hic sapiente culpa modi quo esse!</p>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="" class="svg-icon">
</div>
```

Here's a CodePen demo: https://codepen.io/ricardozea/pen/7869598aa71d7345550f351b00080fac?editors=1100

Comment: You are telling both paragraphs to use the same area, thus they literally use the same space; using CSS Grid seems kinda out of place for this scenario, any particular reason why you want to use grid here?

Comment: Hi Ricardo; as a general rule, unless your question is about how to do something in Sass specifically, CSS questions should include the compiled CSS code instead. This way your CSS question is accessible to everyone who knows CSS and not just those who know CSS *and* Sass.

Comment: @IvanS95, the answer to your question is simple: Because I want to.

Comment: @RicardoZea Fair enough, I added the answer which gets you what you need :)

Comment: @TylerH Makes sense, thanks for the edits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on your code, the reason why its happening, is because you are telling the `p` tags to use the same `grid-area`, which causes both paragraphs to use the exact same space, overlapping each other; this is fixed by simply creating a container which will use the area instead, and the items inside of it will behave normally.

This seems a little weird use case for CSS Grid to me though. Check the snippet and let me know if it works for you :)

```css
.wrapper{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
  grid-template-areas: "avatar name   icon" "avatar date   date" "review review review";
  border: red 1px solid;
}

h3 {
  grid-area: name;
  margin: 0;
}

.svg-icon {
  grid-area: icon;
}

.date {
  grid-area: date;
}

.box {
  grid-area: review;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="">
  <h3>Gene Kang</h3>
  <span class="date">December 29, 2016</span>
  <div class="box">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi harum, voluptatum perferendis       dicta error blanditiis ipsum in nemo expedita delectus. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur           adipisicing elit. Recusandae in eius necessitatibus, impedit
      sapiente cupiditate laudantium perspiciatis neque dolore sequi laborum quo iure facere nobis minima, numquam illo sunt unde?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, maiores consectetur laboriosam distinctio libero pariatur at quasi aliquam ipsam provident eligendi eos quibusdam animi sapiente iste beatae ducimus cum temporibus unde, nobis totam
      odio sed ab! Voluptate soluta explicabo harum? Non, rerum nulla repellat hic sapiente culpa modi quo esse!</p>
  </div>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="" class="svg-icon">
</div>
```

Comment: Much better comment/answer! :). Oh, I see now… If I have to wrap the paragraphs in yet another container that just defeats the use of Grid (this experience is something they can't teach in any tutorial). I can accomplish this same layout with Flexbox as per the new container seems required. Well, lesson learned! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem! Of course the other option is to create another `grid-area` to contain the other paragraph, but again, maybe not the most optimal solution.

Comment: @RicardoZea Indeed, a lot of things Grid layout can do, Flexbox can also already do in a simpler/better way. However, Grid is for those other situations where you need something fixed, and/or with a table layout, where you want to control the inner content across an entire grid area, track, etc. Some stuff can also only be accomplished with the careful combination of Flexbox *and* Grid layout!

Answer (score 2):

I think that you just forgot to get your paragraphs into a single div and give that div the review grid area so the two paragraphs are treated as a single element and they do not overlap each other. Here is a Fiddle.

```css
//Main wrapper
.grid {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
    grid-template-areas:
   "avatar name   icon"
   "avatar date   date"
   "review review review";
    border: red 1px solid;
}
//Avatar
.avatar {
  grid-area: avatar;
}
//Name
h3 {
    grid-area: name;
    margin: 0;
}
//Icon
.svg-icon { grid-area: icon; }
//Date
.date { grid-area: date; }
//Review
.review { grid-area: review; }
```

```html
<div class="grid">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/50" alt="" class="avatar">
    <h3>Gene Kang</h3>
    <span class="date">December 29, 2016</span>
    <div class="review">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eligendi harum, voluptatum perferendis dicta error blanditiis ipsum in nemo expedita delectus. Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae in eius necessitatibus, impedit sapiente cupiditate laudantium perspiciatis neque dolore sequi laborum quo iure facere nobis minima, numquam illo sunt unde?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Voluptatum, maiores consectetur laboriosam distinctio libero pariatur at quasi aliquam ipsam provident eligendi eos quibusdam animi sapiente iste beatae ducimus cum temporibus unde, nobis totam odio sed ab! Voluptate soluta explicabo harum? Non, rerum nulla repellat hic sapiente culpa modi quo esse!</p>
    </div>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/20" alt="" class="svg-icon">
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias Francisco, this is exactly the solution I needed, to wrap the paragraphs in their own container. Gave you an upvote :)